# How can I make it go down to the bottom lines after the response from the promise is returned in the function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a showBoxConfirm function. This function confirms. After pressing the button I want, it will enter the clickMethod function. My result variable will hold the confirm response. if it returns false i will terminate the function. But the showBoxConfirm method is a promise. How do I get it to go down to the bottom lines after submitting?
What I want is condition should work after response return

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <button @click="clickMethod()"> Click </>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      clickMethod() {
         let result = this.showBoxConfirm();
          // What I want is condition should work after response return

          if (!result) return;
      },
      showBoxConfirm() {
        const h = this.$createElement;
        // Using HTML string
        const titleVNode = h("div", {domProps: {innerHTML: "Title from <i>HTML<i> string"}});
        // More complex structure
        const messageVNode = h("div", {class: ["foobar"]}, [
          h("b-img", {
            props: {
              src: "https://picsum.photos/id/20/250/250",
              thumbnail: true,
              center: true,
            },
          }),
          h("p", {class: ["text-center"]}, [
            "Question text?",
          ]),
        ]);
        // We must pass the generated VNodes as arrays
        this.$bvModal
          .msgBoxConfirm([messageVNode], {
            title: [titleVNode],
            size: "sm",
            buttonSize: "sm",
            okVariant: "danger",
            okTitle: "YES",
            cancelTitle: "NO",
            footerClass: "p-2",
            hideHeaderClose: false,
            centered: true,
          })
          .then((value) => {
            return value;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // An error occurred
          });
      },

    },
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 bugs here: 1) `showBoxConfirm` doesn't run a return statement, so it just returns `undefined` which is falsy, and 2) `clickMethod` doesn't know to wait for a response and simply continues immediately after `showBoxConfirm` returns.

#1 is fixed simply by adding `return` to the start of your `this.$bvModal` line - this will return the Promise returned by the `catch` method. (You could also drop the `then` and `catch` calls and just return the Promise returned by `msgBoxConfirm`.)

To fix #2, I'd make `clickMethod` an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and `await` on the Promise returned by `showBoxConfirm`. You could also call the Promise's `then` method to register a function to call when it resolves.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can i see this answer on the code?